# why does arm-linux-androideabi-gcc give iostream error

Tags: android, gcc, linker, arm

I have arm-linux-androideabi-gcc installed in my computer, but when I try to compiler even a simple hellow world, it gives error ( I am choosing not to use ndk-build ) . I just want to compile from the command line ...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    return 0;
}
```

And I received this error:

> error: iostream: No such file or directory

I have the arm-linux-androideabi-gcc in `~/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin` .

I have tried including `-I ~/android-ndk-r7b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr`

I have also tried including `-lstdc++` just to see if it works but no ...

```
./arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -o ff first.cpp -I /home/hari/android-ndk-r7b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr -lstdc++
```

Comment: The problem was with make-standalone-toolchain.sh ... edit this file as this link says -->>  https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/39878/1/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh and thank you Frohnzie for helping me figure this out ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to create the standalone toolchain:

```
make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-14 --install-dir=standalone-toolchain --ndk-dir=$ANDROID_NDK_PATH
```

export the PATH:

```
export PATH=$TOOLCH/standalone-toolchain/bin:$PATH
```

Then build the file:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -o test-new test.cpp
```

Note: issue using revision 8b which is the latest version of the NDK: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35279

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -o test-new test.cpp --sysroot=$TOOLCH/sysroot
-I$TOOLCH/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/include
-I$TOOLCH/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/include-fixed
-I$TOOLCH/arm-linux-androideabi/include/c++/4.6
-I$TOOLCH/arm-linux-androideabi/include/c++/4.6/arm-linux-androideabi
-I$TOOLCH/sysroot/usr/include
```

Comment: thank you Frohnzie for the answer really appreciate it .. now arm-linux-androideabi-gcc works fine now ... i was able to compile with no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error:
    `iostream: No such file or directory`

`#include "iostream"` should be #include `#include <iostream>`

Comment: i did that .. stackoverflow hids the whole string iostream ( strange ... ) when i do that but in my program i do #include <iostream>  .. thank you for the response though ..

Answer (score 0):

According to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35279 , this is a bug of the standalone toolchain. I think the best fix-around is
`ln -s $TOOLCH/arm-linux-androideabi/include/c++/4.6 $TOOLCH/arm-linux-androideabi/include/c++/4.6.x-google`