# How to create an Android executable for launch from the shell?

Tags: c++, shell, android-ndk, apk-expansion-files, dropbear

I'm using eclipse with the NDK to port my C++ application to Android.  On Linux, it is an application that you invoke with arguments in the shell to perform a task, no GUI is provided, it is just a command line interface.  Presently, I have added a very basic GUI wrapper in java that encapsulates the argument specification that is passed to the ported C++ code in the NDK, however, I would like to also have an application that can be invoked when I ssh into my android phone.

On Android, I see that some applications have the ability to be launched from the shell.  For example, the `SSH Droid` installed from the Google Play Store, has in addition to its GUI, a shell invokable version.  I see this under the pathname `/data/data/berserker.android.apps.sshdroid/dropbear/ssh` whereas its APK is located at `/data/app/berserker.android.apps.sshdroid-1.apk`.  For my APK, I find no executables in `/data/data/com.mydomain.myapp-37.apk`, only the directories `cache`, `files`, and `lib`.

Using Eclipse, how can I package natively executable binaries in my application's APK archive?  Once present in my APK, how can I in the installation automate the extraction and setting executable permissions so that I can launch it through the shell?  It would appear that SSH Droid has done both of these things, I would like to do likewise.  Is there a simple example that shows how this is done?

Do I even need an apk, can I somehow just create a command line interface executable more in line with my existing Linux port version?

How are arguments specified for the shell CLI?  Do you use `argc` and `argv` like in C++ applications?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to package native commandline application in apk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383552/how-to-package-native-commandline-application-in-apk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, I didn't need eclipse nor any java code in my application.  My application that was being ported from Linux, already had a set of makefiles already in place.  I was able to use my existing makefile system by way of the standalone tool chain portion of the NDK.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747974/115751) got me going with the standalone tool chain.  In my case, here is how I invoked it where I am cross compiling from my Macintosh, having already installed the NDK at `/Users/me/Development/android-ndk-r10d`:

```
ANDROID_NDK=/Users/me/Development/android-ndk-r10d
SYSROOT=$(ANDROID_NDK)/platforms/android-19/arch-arm
${ANDROID_NDK}/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-19 --install-dir=${ANDROID_NDK}/myapp-android-toolchain --ndk-dir=/Users/me/Development/android-ndk-r10d --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 --system=darwin-x86_64
```

With this setup, I launched my build like this:

```
cd ~/base/of/myapp/src/
ANDROID_NDK=/Users/me/Development/android-ndk-r10d PATH=${ANDROID_NDK}/myapp-android-toolchain/bin:$PATH make
```

After I fixed some issues with config for my cross-compilation in some third-party libraries I'm using, I had a working build.  Next, I wanted to install it on my phone:

```
# Push to a location with write permission (sdcard):
cd ~/base/of/myapp/bin/ # My build puts the executable here.
adb push myapp /sdcard/
# Go into phone and complete the install manually:
adb shell
su
mount -oremount,rw rootfs /system  # /vendor/bin is in /system mount.
# One time creation of /vendor/bin (that is in the PATH by default):
mkdir /vendor/bin
# Copy the myapp executable over
cp /sdcard/myapp /vendor/bin/myapp
```

Now, I can invoke myapp from the shell on my phone, like a normal command line interface Linux application.  The `argc` and `argv` from my original Linux code work as written in the Android build by this process.